# Understanding Haml Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I am currently working with a RoR project where my team is using Haml as a templating engine. I have difficulty understanding the following code.

```
%td
   = link_to 'Edit', [:edit, :merchants, category, subcategory], class: 'btn'
   = link_to 'Delete', [:merchants, category, subcategory], :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn'
```

Which translate into html as

```
<a class="btn" href="/admin/categories/28/sub_categories/147/edit">Edit</a>
<a class="btn" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/admin/categories/28/sub_categories/147" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

From [Haml documentation,](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#object_reference_) I found out that [] notation used for object reference so I am not sure how the [ ] notation translated into href notation. I am pretty new to both Ruby On Rails and Haml, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It nothing about the `Haml`. It is a `Rails` helper what's builds `some_awesome_path` from arrays of `:symbol` and `variables`.

Internally, `Rails` will convert `[:edit, :merchants, category, subcategory]` to a call to `merchants_category_subcategory_path`. Most (if not all) `Rails` methods that expect a path will also take an object representation of your resource, like `respond_with`, `link_to`, `render`, `redirect_to`, `form_for`, etc.

Some example:

This array:

```
[:new, @object, :post]
```

Translate to:

`new_businesses_post_path()` and `new_businesses_post_url()`

[`Creating URLs From Objects`](http://guides.ruby.tw/rails3/routing.html#2-8)

Answer (score 0):

In Rails we have two ways to build pathes

- by `*_path` methods
- by polymorphic pathes http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_url

Also some methods (`form_for`, `link_to`) not requires to call `polymorpic_path` and able to take array directly.